# One-sided limit of q norm on $[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, normed-spaces

I'm trying to show that for $f \in L^q([0,1])$ for all $q$ with $1≤q≤p<\infty$, we have $$\lim_{q \to p^-}||f||_q=||f||_p$$

It's easy to show that $$\lim_{q \to p^-}||f||_q≤||f||_p$$
But the other direction is proving difficult. I've tried to use an epsilon argument similar to what you use to show $$\lim_{p \to \infty}||f||_p=||f||_\infty$$but it hasn't worked out.

Comment: Can  you show in more detailed what you have tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose first that $f\in L^p$. Let $(q_n)$ be a sequence of numbers smaller than $p$ converging to $p$. Then using the dominated convergence theorem, $\lVert f\rVert_{q_n}^{q_n}\to\lVert f\rVert_{p}^{p}$ (bound $\lvert f\rvert^{q_n}$ by
$\lvert f\rvert^p\mathbf{1}_{\{\lvert f\rvert\geqslant 1\}}+\mathbf{1}_{\{\lvert f\rvert\lt 1\}}$).

If $f$ does not belong to $L^p$, let $f_N:=\lvert f\rvert\mathbf{1}_{\{\lvert f\rvert\leqslant N\}}$. Then for all $N\geqslant 1$,
$$
\liminf_{q\to p^-}\lVert f\rVert_q\geqslant \liminf_{q\to p^-}\lVert f_N\rVert_q
=\lVert f_N\rVert_p,$$
where we used what we established in the first paragraph. By monotone convergence, $\lVert f_N\rVert_p\to +\infty$ as $N$ goes to infinity.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on how $||f_N||_p \rightarrow \infty$ yields the result? I'm stuck on trying to see that.

Comment: This gives that $\liminf_{q\to p^-}\lVert f\rVert_q=+\infty$, which gives the result.

Comment: Could you also explain how the case with $f \in L^p$ is enough to conclude that $||f||_p ≤ \lim_{q \to p^-} ||f||_p$? I've spent some time trying understand, but I'm not quite seeing how it works. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

WLOG, $f\ge 0.$ We are letting $q\to p^-,$ where $p\in (0,\infty)$ is fixed. We are assuming $\int_0^1f^p<\infty.$

Observe, as Davide Giraudo pointed out,

$$f^q= f^q\cdot\chi_{\{f\le 1\}} + f^q\cdot \chi_{\{f>1\}}\le 1\cdot\chi_{\{f\le 1\}} + f^p\cdot \chi_{\{f>1\}}$$

for all $q\le p.$ Both summands on the right are in $L^1,$ hence so is their sum. By DCT,

$$\lim_{q\to p^-}\int_0^1 f^q = \lim_{q\to p^-}\int_0^1 \left(f^q\cdot\chi_{\{f\le 1\}} +f^q\cdot \chi_{\{f>1\}}\right)$$ $$ = \int_0^1 \left(f^p\cdot\chi_{\{f\le 1\}} + f^p\cdot \chi_{\{f>1\}}\right) = \int_0^1 f^p.$$

Now

$$\tag1  \|f\|_q = \exp[(1/q)\ln\,(\int_0^1 f^q)].$$

As $q\to p^-,$ use what we have proved, together with continuity, to see the right side of $(1)$ $\to \exp[(1/p)(\ln \int_0^1 f^p)].$ Thus $\|f\|_q\to \|f\|_p$ as desired.

Note we did not have to assume $1\le q.$

Comment: What happens if the integral in the natural log is 0?

Comment: Then $f^q=0$ a.e., which implies $f=0$ a.e. In that case $\|f\|_q=\|f\|_p=0$ for all $0<q\le p$ and then there is nothing to do.